# NLB and Multiple Clusters on 1 Virtual NIC

Tags: nlb

I can't seem to find information on setting up multiple NLB clusters on a single NIC.
I've already setup my first NLB cluster. This is used to load balance traffic to web server running on two hosts.  I am now looking to setup a second web server on each of these hosts. The second web server will given a unique IP address and I'm hoping to create a second NLB cluster instance to support the second web server.
I have bound a second IP address to the network card on each of my hosts. However, when I launch NLB and chose the option to add a new cluster there are no interfaces available to create the cluster.
Has anyone else attempted this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried setting something up quite like you describe, but we do have multiple websites running out of our single Windows Server 2008 R2 NLB cluster.  The NLB interface lets you add additional IP addresses to the cluster itself, so one cluster managing multiple IP addresses should be able to do what you need.  You can then assign the different IP addresses to different web sites.